# Convert a MYSQL query to DB2 query

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

i have a query that works fine in my sql but the same query is giving error in DB2

here is the requirement
 Find the largest country in each continent, show the continent, the name and the population: 
and  herez the query

```
SELECT continent, name, population FROM world x
WHERE population = 
  (SELECT max(population) FROM world y
      WHERE y.continent=x.continent
   )
```

and the error is

```
 [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0206N "Y.CONTINENT" is not valid in the context where
it is used. SQLSTATE=42703 (SQL-42S22)
```

can anybody help me with the changes i need to make to make it work in DB2

you can check the answer here http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial if it working 
its the 6th example ... change the engine to DB2

Comment: This SQL statement is perfectly valid on DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows.  If you are getting this error please provide the output of `describe table world`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
SELECT x.continent, x.name, x.population 
FROM world x
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT continent, max(population) pop
    FROM world
    GROUP BY continent
  ) y ON x.continent = y.continent AND x.population = y.pop
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c11/1) to demonstrate.

Good luck.

Comment: even this query has the same issue ..its working fine for mysql but not for DB2  ...... u can chek here http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial  in the 6th example.....change the engine to DB2

Comment: Hmmm -- could you try using the keyword: LATERAL -- read it might resolve your issue.  Try adding after the FROM clause like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c11/7 -- not sure it will help...

Answer (score 0):

DB2 table 'world' does not have a column called "CONTINENT" it is defined as "REGION". Your query is fine, it is an issue with mismatching table definitions. Below query works perfectly!

```
SELECT REGION, name, population FROM world x
WHERE population = 
  (SELECT max(population) FROM world y
      WHERE y.REGION=x.REGION
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with world x and world y. If these are the names of your tables, try putting them in square brackets [world x] and [world y].

If that is not the case, try specifying max(population). It's either y.population, or x.population